# Как при переходе на сайт через определенное время сменить цвет фона?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как при переходе на сайт через определенное время сменить цвет фона и больше его не менять (до перезагрузки)?

Answer (score 5):

Не очень кроссбраузерно, зато без js. Через 5 секунд запустится переход по цвету фона длительностью 2 секунды.

```css
body {
  animation-name: Name;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-color: blue;
}
@keyframes Name {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Для событий "через определённое время" в JavaScript есть функция `setTimeout`. В ней указываете время в миллисекундах. К примеру, заменим цвет фона на васильковый (`cornflowerblue`) через 2 секунды (2000 миллисекунд):

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("body").css("background-color", "cornflowerblue");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Может он плавно хотел?)

Comment: @Yuri Пусть тогда уточняет, если что сделаю плавно.

Comment: а как сделать тоже самое с фотографией (background: url() ), чтобы одна фотография менялась другой и плавно, если не трудно. Я js совсем не знаю

Comment: @Mr.Tabrest Это уже на другой вопрос тянет, потому что фотография, это другое.

Comment: @Mr.Tabrest либо начинайте изучать JS, либо не занимайтесь подобными задачами. Не будет же кто-то за вас всегда такие задачи решать.

Comment: @Mr.Tabrest Задавайте ещё один отдельный вопрос про смену фотографий, не стесняйтесь, а в этом отметься ответ, как принятый, который вам подходит. Мне, к примеру, больше нравится решение AndreyFedorov.

Answer (score 1):

С JQuery, но кроссбраузерно 100%, даже в ie6 работать будет

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('body').animate({'background-color': '#f60'}, 300);
},5000); // Changing color after 5 sec
```

Без jQuery

```
setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#f60'
}, 5000);
```

а для анимации во втором случае в css добавить

```
body{transition-duration: .3s}
```